# net.Socket.writable, net.Socket.readable properties aren't part of the official node.js API

Tags: api, sockets, node.js

I wonder why are net.Socket.writable and net.Socket.readable properties not part of the official node.js API? Does it mean that it's better not to use these properties since it's an internal stuff which can change in the future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are -- but not where you are looking. `readable` and `writable` are properties of [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), which `net.Socket` inherits from. See [stream.readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and [stream.writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), respectively.